# Django installation has no __init__.py in django.core

Tags: python, django, ubuntu

I have a ubuntu lucid VPS server where I try to run my django development server.

Running `python manage.py runserver` gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named core.management
```

I can import django without any problem in a python shell. I looked in the django install directory and noticed there is no `\__init__.py` in the `django/core` folder. Which I beleive is the source of the problem for python to register `django.core` as a module.

It then looks like an installation issue. I installed django using apt-get.

FYI the django install worked perfectly on my home computer with same OS.

Any ideas?

Comment: it's really hard to answer with so little information. What's the error you're getting after adding the \_\_init__.py file?

Comment: if I create the \__init__.py file and try the runserver again I get a ImportError: No module named commands.startapp. Certainly another init file missing for that package as well.

Comment: Well, you can either recurse into every directory in the django installation and make sure there is an `__init__.py` file or try another installation method. `apt-get` is a very poor way to install Django, as Ubuntu repositories infrequently and sometimes never updated for the installed Ubuntu version (you often need to upgrade the entire OS to get the latest package version). For Python itself, apt-get is fine, but for packages, you should be using easy_install or pip.

Comment: Quick look at the files you mention, in my django 1.3 install, shows that these are empty `__init__.py` files - so your installation is probably dropping 0-byte files. Per @ChrisPratt, try another installation method that is more Python-aware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solved.

Thank you for all the suggestions. I installed django using the tar ball as instructed in the django website.

apt-get is not a good idea to install django. I also had to manually remove the left over django folder in /usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6 after using apt-get remove.